# Applescript Terminal with OSX 10.8

Tags: java, scripting, terminal, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

i wrote my first script for downloading downloads reports via Apple's autoingestion.class. 
It works fine most of the time with OSX 10.7.5, but under OSX 10.8 it sometimes renames files or puts the text for terminal in the applescript editor itself.

Anyone knows how to solve / improve this?

```
tell application "Terminal"
activate
delay 1 #give time to activate Terminal

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "cd " & ingestPath #path to autoingestion.class
    keystroke return
    keystroke "java Autoingestion " & userName & " " & userPW & " " & vendorID & " S D S " & reportDate
    keystroke return
end tell

delay 0.1
set frontWindow to window 1
repeat until busy of frontWindow is false
    delay 1
end repeat
#display dialog "finished"
#quit end tell
```

Thx for your time guys

**Edit1:**
Thx for the fast answer!! I tried the second part and it gives me an Java error, any ideas?
Ill try the delay-thing as soon as i got the other macbook again.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ USER$ java '/Volumes/STICK/Projekte/App_Statstiken/Apple/sales/Autoingestion' USERNAME PW VENDORID S D S 20130718
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /Volumes/STICK/Projekte/App_Statstiken/Apple/sales/Autoingestion
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .Volumes.STICK.Projekte.App_Statstiken.Apple.sales.Autoingestion
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

**Edit2:**
FYI: Updated to new autoingestion.class which uses a propertie to save userName and userPW.

```
set exePath to ingestPath 
do script "java -cp " & (exePath & space & "Autoingestion autoingestion.properties" & space & vendorID & " S D S " & reportDate)
```

gives the **error** that the **autoingestion.properties is missing**, altough

```
keystroke "java Autoingestion " & "autoingestion.properties" & " " & vendorID & " S D S " & reportDate
```

is working. I tried to put the path in front of the propertie file, but didnt helped. 
Any ideas?

**Working:**

```
do script "cd " & ingestPath & ";java Autoingestion " & userName & " " & userPW & " " & vendorID & " S D S " & reportDate
```

Comment: Why not just make a bash script for this? Does it have to be AS?

Comment: cause i never wrote bash yet. Also the script does a little more. checks, downloads, unzips and moves the file. Also it was planed to put the newly downloaded data into excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times with keystrokes, the applescript code runs faster than the computer interface can perform the typing... so you have issues. The solution is to put short delays between the typing commands to give the computer interface time to perform the typing. Also your System Events code should not be inside the "tell application Terminal" block of code.

Try this. You can play with the normalDelay and shortDelay times to make them longer or shorter as needed.

```
set normalDelay to 1
set shortDelay to 0.2

tell application "Terminal" to activate
delay normalDelay --give time to activate Terminal

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "cd " & ingestPath --path to autoingestion.class
    delay shortDelay
    keystroke return
    delay shortDelay
    keystroke "java Autoingestion " & userName & " " & userPW & " " & vendorID & " S D S " & reportDate
    delay shortDelay
    keystroke return
    delay shortDelay
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    set frontWindow to window 1
    repeat until busy of frontWindow is false
        delay normalDelay
    end repeat
end tell

display dialog "finished"
```

***Note***: I haven't tried this but you may be able to simplify your code as follows...

```
set exePath to ingestPath & "Autoingestion"

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "java " & quoted form of exePath & space & userName & space & userPW & space & vendorID & " S D S " & reportDate

    set frontWindow to window 1
    repeat until busy of frontWindow is false
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell

display dialog "finished"
```

***EDIT***: if you're having problems with the path and other errors (as indicated in your comments) then maybe this approach would work. Try this as your do script command. If the keystroke method works then this will act just like that.

```
do script "cd " & ingestPath & ";java Autoingestion " & userName & " " & userPW & " " & vendorID & " S D S " & reportDate
```

Comment: thx for the answer, see Edit1 pls ;)
ill guess its smth with the class description
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .Volumes.STICK.Projekte.App_Statstiken.Apple.sales.Autoingestion"
But how to fix?

Comment: I think on Mountain Lion, Java is not installed with the OS. Maybe you need to install it? Just a guess. http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml

Comment: not working under osx 10.7.5 with java installed. there seems to be a problem with the path for the do script command

Comment: FYI: Updated to new autoingestion.class which uses a propertie to save userName and userPW.

set exePath to ingestPath
 do script "java -cp " & (exePath & space & "Autoingestion autoingestion.properties" & space & vendorID & " S D S " & reportDate)
gives the error that the autoingestion.properties is missing, altough
keystroke "java Autoingestion " & "autoingestion.properties" & " " & vendorID & " S D S " & reportDate
is working. I tried to put the path in front of the propertie file, but didnt helped. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't use Autoingestion so I don't know how it works, but there's one other idea you could try. See the "Edit" section at the bottom of my post.